# Perennial crop purely for compost for a no dig bed - what crop and what area?

Tags: composting

I am using a no dig system and want to generate my own compost.

I am thinking of a wild area of perennials regularly mown/cut purely for comoposting.

What would a good crop (or mix) be? And how much would I need for each 1m<sup>3</sup> of compost each year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comfrey "Bocking 14" is often given as a good source of biomass.  [Observations](https://www.thepolycultureproject.com/comfrey-trials.html) made at one site over a two year period found that a 13m² bed (42 plants) of comfrey produced nearly 100 kg of cuttings per season over a two year period, or enough material to mulch an 18m² bed to a depth of 10-15 cm (or between 1.8m³ and 2.7m³).

Comfrey is a vigorous perennial.  The "Bocking 14" strain is sterile, limiting its ability to escape your chosen growing site.